# Illegal operand for constant expression

Tags: verilog, cadence

I'm trying to build a task, which must delve into some hierarchy, that can concisely compare different pins on a particular instance. In particular, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
task check_expected;
  input integer pin;
  input [9:0] expected;
  integer i, j;
  reg [9:0] check;
  begin
    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1) begin
      case (pin)
        0: begin
          check[0] = test.inst[i].lane_0.PIN_FIRST;
          check[1] = test.inst[i].lane_1.PIN_FIRST;
          ...
          check[9] = test.inst[i].lane_9.PIN_FIRST;
        end
        1: begin
          check[0] = test.inst[i].lane_0.PIN_SECOND;
          check[1] = test.inst[i].lane_1.PIN_SECOND;
          ...
          check[9] = test.inst[i].lane_9.PIN_SECOND;
        end
        ...
        9: begin
          check[0] = test.inst[i].lane_0.PIN_TENTH;
          check[1] = test.inst[i].lane_1.PIN_TENTH;
          ...
          check[9] = test.inst[i].lane_9.PIN_TENTH;
        end
      endcase

      if (check[0] !== expected[j*10 + 0]) begin
        TEST_FAILED = TEST_FAILED + 1;
        $display("ERROR Expected=%b,  @ %0t",expected[j*10 + 0],$time);
      end
      if (check[1] !== expected[j*10 + 1]) begin
        TEST_FAILED = TEST_FAILED + 1;
        $display("ERROR Expected=%b,  @ %0t",expected[j*10 + 1],$time);
      end
      ...
      if (check[9] !== expected[j*10 + 9]) begin
        TEST_FAILED = TEST_FAILED + 1;
        $display("ERROR Expected=%b,  @ %0t",expected[j*10 + 9],$time);
      end
    end
  end
endtask
```

Unfortunately, attempting to do the above throws a NOTPAR error during elaboration, claiming that it is unacceptable to assign a register to a non-constant (it doesn't like any lines like `check[0] = test.inst[i].lane_0.PIN_FIRST;`). This is just for testing purposes, not anything synthesizeable, by the way.

Can someone explain why this is disallowed and suggest a different solution? It's looking like I'll need to write a task for each and every loop iteration, and that seems like it would be needlessly bloated and ugly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the answer is that there is no way to do it with Verilog. Verilog is an incredibly dumb (in terms of capabilities) language, and, with a task, can only support constant indices for module instances. No looping is possible.

Comment: I think you are being a bit too harsh on Verilog! What is the version of your simulator? Verilog 2001 supports generate loops. Have you tried writing your code using such a loop?  http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/online_verilog_ref_guide/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf

Comment: I have 2001 enabled. The problem isn't generate loops (I've got those for the actual design). What I wanted above was just a test for bypass logic, hence why I need to delve into (pre-existing) hierarchy. Generate statements in this test context are not valid, I just need a way to loop through values on existing multiple module instances. Unfortunately, Verilog does not allow this type of looping; all indices must be explicitly specified, so any loops must be unrolled by hand.